# SkLearn estimator error in NearestNeighbors

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Here is my code:

```
for k in range(1, 50):
  neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=k)
  neigh.fit(data, dataClass) 
  a = sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score(neigh, data, y=dataClass, cv=kf)
```

Error

```
If no scoring is specified, the estimator passed should have a 'score' method. The estimator NearestNeighbors(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
     metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=1, p=2, radius=1.0) does not.
```

If I try to pass parameter scoring='accuracy' it gives me the following error:

```
  'NearestNeighbors' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

What do I do?
Documentaition says NearestNeighbors have .score and .predict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NearestNeighbors will only give you the neighbors, i think you need to try KNeighborsClassifier. Try this:

```
from sklearn import neighbors, cross_validation

for k in range(1, 50):
  neigh = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
  neigh.fit(data, dataClass) 
  a = cross_validation.cross_val_score(neigh, data, y=dataClass, cv=kf)
```

Comment: For searchers, `cross_validation` is deprecated since v0.18, for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53978901/importerror-cannot-import-name-cross-validation-from-sklearn