# ImportError: cannot import name 'cross_validation' from 'sklearn'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Here is my code Please Help. I'm a beginner.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import sklearn
    from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
    from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn import cross_validation
```

I'm using the latest version of Sklearn but I'm getting this error

On Windows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "MalwareDetector.py", line
>   8, in 
>       from sklearn import cross_val_score ImportError: cannot import name 'cross_val_score' from 'sklearn'
>   (C:\Users\richa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn__init__.py)

On Ubuntu:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "MalwareDetector.py", line 8,
>   in  from sklearn import cross_validation ImportError: cannot
>   import name cross_validation

Answer (score 76):

`cross_validation` is deprecated since version 0.18. This module will be removed in 0.20.

Use sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split instead.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

More:
[sklearn 0.19 docs](https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html)

Comment: Should that say `from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split` instead of `from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate`

Comment: @tscizzle you're right